# Why does archiving build not work properly? SwiftUI Xcode 14 iOS 16

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, archive, testflight

Hello I am trying to archive my app to push to testflight but I get errors saying "Cannot Find '[insert file name].swift' in scope".

Building and running on phone works as expected. It is just when I try to archive, there are specific SwiftUi files that cannot be found in scope for whatever reason.

Things I've tried: cleaning, restarting XCode, deleting derived data. I've made sure that all files have the proper target membership for it to be included in the build.

XCode version 14.2; iOS support min 16

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There's no known issues with that sort of thing, so it must be your project. What exactly in your project, impossible to say with that little information

Comment: First clear DerivedData and close and re-open Xcode re-run and see if it builds correctly. Usually Run uses the `Debug` configuration and `Release` uses configuration. This can be changed. SwiftUI builds correctly on iOS 16, it is a bug at your end. Check your build phases.